# service mysql reload results 'Access denied', but service mysql start works

Tags: debian, permissions, mysql

Using Debian 10.10.

I have a MySQL problem.

```
service mysql reload
```

results 'Access denied'

```
service mysql start
```

executes correctly.

All databases are working correctly after starting mysql. Strange, that reloading results access denied error.

Connecting to mysql with

```
mysql -p -u root -h localhost
```

connects successfully.

Only mysqladmin has problems:

```
mysqladmin start
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

mysqladmin reload
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Any idea what is the problem with mysqladmin?
Maybe some permission problem?